# Given a line $p$ and a point $T$, how do I fint the mirrored point $T'$ over $p$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p$ be a line given with $\vec{r} \times \vec{p} = \vec{b}$, where $\vec{p} \neq \vec{0}$ and $\vec{p} \perp \vec{b}$. Point $T$ is given with a position vector $\vec{t}$.
I need to find a position vector of a point $T'$ which is a mirror image of $T$ according to line $p$.
So I have to mirror $T$ over $p$ to get $T'$.

I wanted to make a plane which contains $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{r}$ that has a normal vector $\vec{b}$. But I can not get the point on the line $p$ that would be the closest to $T$.
I also tried with a plane that goes through $T$ and $p$ but again, could not determine the right point.
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ is a unit vector in the line direction, then the projection of $T$ onto $p$ is $T_p = (T \cdot u) u = (\|T\| \cos \theta) u$ is the closest point on $p$ to $T$. Can you use that to finish finding the reflection?

Comment: Thank you for this insight. This is helpful. But I am still struggling to get it all together.

Comment: @Coupeau Break $T$ into two parts, $T = T_p + T_\perp$, the part parallel to $p$ is $T_p$ and the part perpendicular to $p$ is $T_\perp = T - T_p$. Then, $T^\prime$ is just going to have the opposite sign of $T_\perp$, so $T^\prime = T_p - T_\perp$.

Comment: $p$ might not pass through the origin.